# add button in show.jspx in a spring roo mvc project

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo, neo4j

I've created a spring roo project using 'Getting started with spring roo' as a starting point. The project is created in STS using roo 1.1.5. I've added neo4j graph and is able to create nodes with simple edges and create the web-part issuing 'controller all --package ~.web'.

The project is a simple web-app with a Person and Race node and a Participant-edge with start-time, end-time, total-time and race-id. Since the edge Participant is a @RelatedToVia it becomes a @RelationshipEntity and I want to add a button to save Participant.

I found WEB-INF/tags/form/field/table.tagx where the add-, modify-, delete-buttons and friends are defined, ie.:

```
      <c:if test="${update}">
        <td class="utilbox">
```

..

But where do I set the variable update? I've looked through the code that is created by STS, but unable to find it. Pardon if this is obvious.

regards
Claus

Edit:

I found out that WEB-INF/tags/form/show.tagx have the knobs to enable/disable for instance the update-button:

```
<c:if test="${empty update}">
  <c:set var="update" value="true" />
</c:if>
```

So I will add my new button in this file. The spring framework seems so well laid out. Just have to find the various places.

regards
Claus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for `update` is obtained from attributes you specify when you use the tag created using the `tagx`.

For an example,

If `form:table` was used as in a `jspx` and if the following was set, you will recieve `true` in your `update` variable if it was assigned using a directive. However it seems that the `true` is set as default in the `form:table` tag within Spring Roo.

If you want to set it to false, when using you have to set the value to the attribute as following.

`<form:table update="false" />`

If you want to go deeper into this, look in to the `table.tagx` file you have mentioned you will find the following line which explains it.

`<jsp:directive.attribute name="update" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Include 'update' link into table (default true)" />`

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was just about to update my answer when I read your reply. ;-)